# Div won't show on hover

Tags: html, css

Want to show a div ontop of an image when the image is hovered, I've written what would I assume to be correct from a number of sources here on stackoverflow but when I hover nothing displays.

```
.hover-state{
position: absolute;
padding: 80px 50px;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 250px;
height: 220px;
top: 19px;
left: 19px;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
}

.portfolio a img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
transition: all 0.1;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
display: block;
margin: 15px 0px;
border: 1px solid #dcdbdb;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.portfolio-item a img:hover .hover-state{
display: block;
}


<div class="row portfolio">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 portfolio-item">
        <div class="hover-state">
            <p>title</p>
            <em>Click me</em>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.catgossip.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-glasses-cat-2.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4LLmj8w1/1/

Comment: `.portfolio-item a img:hover .hover-state` implies a .hover-state inside an image-tag which is hovered. but the image tag you specify has nothing in it. The hover-state div is a sister-node to it rather than a child-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/4LLmj8w1/3/

changed `img:hover` to `.portfolio-item:hover .hover-state`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how css works.

Reorder your link and your div, attach `:hover` to the anchor, not the image, and add the sibling selector `+`:

```
.portfolio-item a:hover + .hover-state{ display:: block; }
```

To remove the flickering, add the hover style to .hover-state as well:

```
.portfolio-item a:hover + .hover-state, .hover-state:hover { display: block; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4LLmj8w1/5/

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
.portfolio-item a img:hover .hover-state{
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
.portfolio-item:hover .hover-state{
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.hover-state{
 position: absolute;
 padding: 80px 50px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 250px;
 height: 220px;
 top: 19px;
 left: 19px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}

.portfolio a img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 transition: all 0.1;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
 display: block;
 margin: 15px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #dcdbdb;
 background-color: #ffffff;
   padding: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.portfolio-item:hover .hover-state{
 display: block;
}

.portfolio-item{
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row portfolio">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 portfolio-item">
        <div class="hover-state">
            <p>title</p>
            <em>Click me</em>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.catgossip.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-glasses-cat-2.jpg" ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```